# How to find properties of an object?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

How can I find what properties object `$a` has in the following?

```
$a = 1
$a.length
$a | Get-Member
```

[Get-Member](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849928.aspx) does not seem to produce any properties for object `$a`? Is length a `property` of object `$a`?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

$a is an Integer, it doesn't have a length property. Using Get-member is the right way to find object properties.

Comment: an integer does not have any member with the name length. So length means nothing to an integer. A string however does have a length property. $a = 'a string'; $a.length

Comment: It can also be a member of a collection (item count): $a=1,2,3; $a.Length

Comment: @ShayLevy Are you saying that `Get-Member` works for integers, or that it doesn't?

Answer (score 14):

You can also pipe a sample object to [Select-Object](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849895.aspx) to see all properties and their values.

```
get-process | select -first 1 -prop *
```

Comment: Next time you post some code select it and click on the `{}` button. Also, posting a link to an article by you is good, but try to disclose that next time, and I hope you don't overdo it in the coming answers. :)